# Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, java-8, iso8601

I'm a little bit frustrated of java 8 date format/parse functionality. I was trying to find Jackson configuration and `DateTimeFormatter` to parse  `"2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000"` string to any Java 8 date, and didn't find it.
This is `java.util.Date` example which works fine:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZZZ")
                      .parse("2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000");
```

The same format doesn't work with new date time api

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000",
                   DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"));
```

We should be able to format/parse date in any format suitable for FE UI application. Maybe I misunderstand or mistake something, but I think `java.util.Date` gives more format flexibility and easier to use.

Comment: I think it doesn't like that fact that there's no am/pm marker, so `10` can be either, trying using `HH` instead `hh` ... or add a `am/pm` marker

Comment: There's a comprehensive answer on how to handle multiple ISO-8601 representations in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487403/java-8-date-and-time-parse-iso-8601-string-without-colon-in-offset

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## tl;dr

Until bug is fixed:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" )
)
```

When bug is fixed:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" )
```

## Details

You are using the wrong classes.

Avoid the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. Now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class you used is good, it is part of java.time. But it is intended for a full time zone. Your input string has merely an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A full time zone, in contrast, is a collection of offsets in effect for a region at different points in time, past, present, and future. For example, with Daylight Saving Time (DST) in most of North America, the offsets change twice a year growing smaller in the Spring as we shift clocks forward an hour, and restoring to a longer value in the Autumn when we shift clocks back an hour.

### `OffsetDateTime`

For only an offset rather than a time zone, use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

Your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" );
```

Well, that *should* have worked. Unfortunately, there is a **bug in Java 8** (at least up through Java 8 Update 121) where that class fails to parse an offset omitting the colon between hours and minutes. So the bug bites on `+0000` but not `+00:00`. So until a fix arrives, you have a choice of two workarounds: (a) a hack, manipulating the input string, or (b) define an explicit formatting pattern.

The hack: Manipulate the input string to insert the colon.

```
String input = "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

#### `DateTimeFormatter`

The more robust workaround is to define and pass a formatting pattern in a `DateTimeFormatter` object.

```
String input = "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-02-13T10:20:12.120Z

By the way, here is a tip: I have found that with many protocols and libraries, your life is easier if your offsets always have the colon, always have both hours and minutes (even if minutes are zero), and always use a padding zero (`-05:00` rather than `-5`).

#### `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

For a more flexible formatter, created via [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), see [this excellent Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488425/642706) on a duplicate Question.

### `Instant`

If you want to work with values that are always in UTC (and you should), extract an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to view that moment through the lens of some region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/CSYGHW).

All of this has been covered many times in many Answers for many Questions. Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. You would have discovered many dozens, if not hundreds, of examples.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Your example throws Exception. What i'm doing wrong.  java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000' could not be parsed at index 23

Comment: Yep, just updated my Answer. I forgot about a formatting parsing bug over the optional colon in offset, fixed in Java 9. [Try my revised code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/CSYGHW).

Comment: This answer should link to the JDK bug. A quick search resulted in https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8032051, but I'm not sure it's the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the mentioned issue. And this got fixed. It's now possible to parse a date of the form `2018-08-26T15:00:00+01`, but `2018-08-26T15:00:00+0100` **still raises an exception**. Tested with OpenJDK 11.

Comment: @BasilBourque Any advice on how to pass the DateTimeFormatter into a RestTemplate, so it will parse both?

Comment: @BasilBourque https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676382/how-do-i-update-resttemplate-to-correctly-map-java-dates

Comment: @deworde Good question; I upvoted. I don’t know the answer. Tip: I have seen other libraries choke on abbreviated offset-from-UTC strings. Best to change the source of your data to always use full length, `+08:00` rather than `+0800` or `+8`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Ended up switching to using Joda time, because I can't change the source.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is a bug: [JDK-8176547](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176547) explains that `+0000` is in "basic" format but `+00:00` is in "extended" format. `java.time` is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) to use extended format. It sounds like the `DateTimeFormatter` (or `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`) solution above is the way to go.

Comment: There is no bug here, so this answer is currently wrong. The problem with the OPs code is using `ZonedDateTime` instead of `OffsetDateTime` and `hh` instead of `HH`. Thus the correct pattern is "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ" which uses "+0000" not "Z" for the offset. The bug you are looking at is about allowing offsets that only have hours, which is a separate issue. See the full range of pattern letters: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

### Short: Not a bug, just your pattern is wrong.

Please use the type `OffsetDateTime` which is especially designed for time zone offsets and use a pattern this way:

```
OffsetDateTime odt =
    OffsetDateTime.parse( 
        "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ" )
    )
```

### Problems in detail:

**a) 12-hour-clock versus 24-hour-clock**

"h" indicates the hour of AM/PM on a 12-hour-clock but you obviously need "H" for the 24-hour-clock as required by ISO-8601.

**b) The form of zero offset**

If you want to parse zero offset like "+0000" instead of "Z" (as described in ISO-paper) you should not use the pattern symbol "X" but "ZZZ". Citing the [pattern syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Offset Z: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
>   letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute,
>   without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the
>   offset is zero.

**c) Your input is NOT ISO-8601-compatible therefore no bug in Java**

Your assumption that "2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000" shall be valid ISO is wrong because you are mixing basic format (in the offset part) and extended format which is explicitly prohibited in ISO-paper (see sections 4.3.2 (example part) and 4.3.3d). Citing ISO-8601:

> [...]the expression shall either be completely in basic format, in which
>   case the minimum number of separators necessary for the required
>   expression is used, or completely in extended format[...]

The statement of B. Bourque that `java.time` has a bug is based on the same wrong expectation about ISO-compatibility. And the documentation of let's say `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` describes the support of the extended ISO-format only. See also the related [JDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176547). Not all ISO-8601-variants are directly supported hence a pattern-based construction of the parser in the right way is okay.

Comment: The link to the JDK issue is extremely helpful to understand the issue. The nuance of the "extended" vs. "basic" format is not going to be immediately obvious to most programmers. The part of the specification where it must be completely in extended format or not at all is most definitely cumbersome and causes workarounds for incoming dates which might not strictly adhere. Maybe this isn't strictly a JDK bug, but it would have been nice if the JDK could be a little more forgiving here and just do the right thing. Good references though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**if offset +0000 try this**

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" )
LocalDate from =LocalDate.parse("2018-02-13T10:20:12.120+0000",f);
```