# SimpleDateFormat mask for 2020-12-21T13:00:00.000+0000

Tags: java, groovy, simpledateformat, boomi

A date/time value is stored in our server as UTC which is correct. But when the server queries the date, it converts it to the server local time zone which is not necessarily the time zone of the device that has initiated the query. I am trying to simply adjust the time, based upon input parameters, to return it to UTC so it can be returned to the application in UTC. But when I try to parse the date so I can adjust the time, I run into a mask error.

I am having difficulty getting the right mask for this format:  2020-12-21T13:00:00.000+0000

Input Value: **2021-01-28T12:30:00.000+0000**

Attempted mask: **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss**

Error:   **No signature of method: java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse() is
applicable for argument types: (java.util.Date) values: {Thu Jan 28 12:30:00 UTC 2021} (in groovy script);
Caused by: No signature of method: java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse() is applicable for argument types:
(java.util.Date) values: {Thu Jan 28 12:30:00 UTC 2021}**

Code:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar; 
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.util.Date; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat inDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat outDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
int minutesToAdd = (Hours * 60) + Minutes ;  
Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date D = inDate.parse(InputDate);
if (D!='')
     {
      C.setTime(D);
      C.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToAdd);
      OutputDate=outDate.format(C.getTime());
     }
else
     {
      OutputDate = ''
     }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You are already passing a date into parse according to this error.
Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: JavaScript or Java? --- `java.text.` makes me think Java.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Related: [Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360852/cannot-parse-string-in-iso-8601-format-lacking-colon-in-offset-to-java-8-date)

Comment: I added the code.  It fails on java.util.Date D = inDate.parse(InputDate);  TY

Comment: This is the format of the DateTime being returned from SalesForce

Comment: Thank you evolutionxbox it is a Groovy 1.5 script

Comment: Above code works fine after massaging it to actually be stand-alone.
I stand with my assessment, that `InputDate` is already
a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @cfrick TY that makes sense.  The input parameter type is being controlled by Boomi and as you said I suspect it is of type java.util.Date.

Comment: @cfrick So do you know of any solution since I am trapped using the java.util.Date?  TY for your time

Comment: Not parsing a date that is already a date? I am quite confused about
what you are asking.

Comment: @cfrick The date is stored as UTC which is correct.  But when the server queries the date, it converts it to the server local time zone which is not necessarily the time zone of the device that has initiated the query.  I am trying to simply adjust the time, based upon input parameters, to return it to UTC so it can be returned to the application in UTC.  But when I try to parse the date so I can adjust the time, I run into the mask issue.  Some have said it is because there is no colon in the Time Zone portion of the data.  I may be approaching this wrong.  TY for your help.

Comment: @cfrick LOL really stupid of me.  TY, I can just pass InputDate as is to the Calendar function now that I know it is the proper type.  I will delete the post but I wanted you to see the comments first.  I appreciate the help.  TY

Comment: Even if in hindsight it looks stupid, please consider whether others could make a similar oversight and benefit from your question and your finding. If so it’s better to answer your own question (so not delete it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cfrick suspected, the value being passed into the Groovy script from Boomi was of type java.util.Date and thus no parsing was needed.

TY